# Search query returning users own id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't understand what is wrong with this query, it returns the current users own id/data despite the AND clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM `User`
WHERE
user_name LIKE
'%a%'
OR
user_fname LIKE
'%a%'
OR
user_sname LIKE
'%a%'
AND
user_id != 38
ORDER BY
user_name,
user_sname,
user_fname
```

Does anyone have any idea why the and clause isn't removing 38 from the list?

Thank you

Comment: Just add parentheses so the AND and ORs are parsed the way you intend.

Comment: Thank you that did it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your condition in `WHERE` like below; basically parenthesize them since `AND` have higher precedence than `OR` condition

```
WHERE (user_name LIKE '%a%'
OR user_fname LIKE '%a%'
OR user_sname LIKE '%a%')
AND
user_id != 38
```

Comment: Great thank you for your quick reply thats great, I will mark as answered when I am allowed to :)

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE (user_name LIKE '%a%'
OR user_fname LIKE '%a%'
OR user_sname LIKE '%a%')
AND
user_id != 38
```

**This will work**